# Python detect alternative peaks

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have the following signal data:

[image: schema]

The Signal is in **RED**, the rolling mean is in **GREY**.

I would like to find a way to identify the indexes where there are successive positive and negative peaks around the mean within a thresold value.

For example, for a thresold of 0,08 it will detect the 22, 35, 36, second mark...

I have no idea how to detect these peaks. Has someone already had this use case?

Comment: It's not exactly clear which peaks you're trying to detect. Threshold 0.08 is not even visible on your graph. Could you detail more, even annotate the graph ?

Comment: Agreed to the parent, could you provide an example of what do you expect as output? Also, rolling mean's window size, if possible?

Comment: I believe I can do this for you in a robust way.  Can you please post the data or a link,  as an ascii file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two lists of values, `x` and `y`.  And you also have a list of values for the rolling mean, but maybe this isn't necessary.  If you want to identify the spikes, you can subtract the previous value of the `y` series to get the size of the difference between adjacent values:

```
spikes = [0.0] + [abs(y[i]-y[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(y))]
```

[image]

Then the spikes you are interested in have a value greater than 0.16 (0.08 above the mean, 0.08 below).  You can find these like this:

```
threshold = 0.08
spike_locations = [x[i] for i in range(len(spikes)) if spikes[i] > 2 * threshold]

[22.0, 35.0, 36.0]
```